# Where is the Flyout control in WinRT XAML?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

The Flyout control in JavaScript is handy for the Settings pane and for button Flyout extensions. But where is the Flyout control for WinRT XAML?

Comment: I might also recommend looking here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/how-to-create-windows-8-settings-pane.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The control you are looking for is called Popup in XAML. Unlike the JavaScript implementation of Flyout, it is up to you location the subject button and position the Popup near it.

Look: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/how-to-create-windows-8-settings-pane.html

Comment: Can the flyout be used as a data entry screen as well?

Answer (score 4):

use [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto) control toolkit, it has flyout control

Comment: I would like to second your suggestion here. Callisto is an excellent toolkit to solve real gaps in the current toolkit.