# Flyout Pane in C# Windows Store (Metro) app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How do we make Flyout Panes (like the ones that flyout when you open a Charms options) in our metro apps? I can only find JavaScript samples in the documentation and there doesn't seem to be any support for it in C# documentation. Am I correct?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965886/where-is-the-flyout-control-in-winrt-xaml

Answer (score 0):

Flyout are not available for XAML/C# Windows 8 store apps. However they are available in 3rd party tool-kits like [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto).

Note: Microsoft has added Flyout in Windows 8.1